# Kube dashboard and calico network in pending state

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, ubuntu-16.04, kubernetes

I am following the below blog to create a kubernetes cluster (on AWS EC2).

https://www.edureka.co/blog/install-kubernetes-on-ubuntu

I completed executing the commands till master config. But dashboard and calico network is stuck on pending state. Googled and found many resources which are not useful in my case, for example: some faced issues because of scheduler unavailability. Here, I have that. And I am very much sure that I have executed all those steps one by one, without fail. Here's the result:

```
kubectl get pods -o wide --all-namespaces
NAMESPACE     NAME            READY   STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE   IP    NODE  NOMINATED NODE   READINESS GATES

kube-system   calico-kube-controllers-694687c474-r55p7   0/1     Pending   0          18m   <none>          <none>    <none>           <none>
kube-system   coredns-86c58d9df4-25fxt                   0/1     Pending   0          33m   <none>          <none>    <none>           <none>
kube-system   coredns-86c58d9df4-w6mfx                   0/1     Pending   0          33m   <none>          <none>    <none>           <none>
kube-system   etcd-kmaster                               1/1     Running   0          37m   172.31.40.185   kmaster   <none>           <none>
kube-system   kube-apiserver-kmaster                     1/1     Running   0          37m   172.31.40.185   kmaster   <none>           <none>
kube-system   kube-controller-manager-kmaster            1/1     Running   0          37m   172.31.40.185   kmaster   <none>           <none>
kube-system   kube-proxy-l4wr6                           1/1     Running   0          38m   172.31.40.185   kmaster   <none>           <none>
kube-system   kube-scheduler-kmaster                     1/1     Running   0          37m   172.31.40.185   kmaster   <none>           <none>
kube-system   kubernetes-dashboard-57df4db6b-s7pzt       0/1     Pending   0          16m   <none>          <none>    <none>           <none>
```

As you can see, its been more than 15 minutes its in pending state for calico and kube dashboard. Any other solutions/ideas would really be appreciated.

Comment: kubectl pod describe kubernetes-dashboard-57df4db6b-s7pzt  -n kube-system

Answer (score 0):

I remember I had similar question in which the same tutorial was linked. You have to use up to date links.

You can either do `kubeadm reset` and run the init again and then use the links from [1](https://docs.projectcalico.org/v2.0/getting-started/kubernetes/installation/). Or you can go for

`kubectl delete -f https://docs.projectcalico.org/v3.0/getting-started/kubernetes/installation/hosted/kubeadm/1.7/calico.yaml`

and I don't know how you have installed dashboard, because the link from the tutorial is showing 404. The up to date yaml can be found [here](https://github.com/kubernetes/dashboard).

[1](https://docs.projectcalico.org/v2.0/getting-started/kubernetes/installation/)For Calico I am using this two files (and 192.168.0.0/16)
`kubectl apply -f https://docs.projectcalico.org/v3.2/getting-started/kubernetes/installation/hosted/rbac-kdd.yaml`

`kubectl apply -f https://docs.projectcalico.org/v3.2/getting-started/kubernetes/installation/hosted/kubernetes-datastore/calico-networking/1.7/calico.yaml`

You can find more details about Calico requirements and installation guide [here](https://docs.projectcalico.org/v2.0/getting-started/kubernetes/installation/).

Also [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52831423/unable-to-install-kubernetes-dashboard-on-aws/53191394#53191394) you can check my previous answer and it also was related to this tutorial. It might be helpful in your next steps.